# Zend Framework 2 layout.phtml

Tags: layout, zend-framework2

So, as I can write code in the controller to affect the view...
What code does the layout.phtml read from? 
(I am assuming the module.php, but I'd like some feedback)

EDIT:
to be clear... in my controller, I can get a variable equal to something and access it in my view. I'd like to discover a similar action inside my layout.

thanks

Comment: Can you give us a use case to prepare example

Comment: Until then, maybe [Akrabats Layout Examples](http://zf2test.akrabat.com/) will help you out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You ask various questions in this single post. I will try to address a few of them.

**How does  a layout work?**

In Zend Framework 2 there is the concept of "view models". A view model is an object that has a couple of variables and a template assigned. This template is rendered with the given variables.

Furthermore, you can nest view models. So one view model (the "layout") has a child which is created from your controller. The child is rendered and stored as a variable in the parent view model. The name of this variable is called the "capture to".

What happens, is you have a controller and then a view model is created. This view model is inserted as a *child view model* in a new model, which is the layout. This child is set with a "capture to" of `content`. So in the layout, the result of the child view model is inserted in the `$content` variable.

**How do you access layout variables in the controller?**

There is a a `layout` controller plugin which gives you *direct access to the layout view model*. So you can set variables directly there:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->layout()->setVariable('foo', 'bar');
}
```

Then `$foo` echos `bar` in your layout.

**How do you access layout variables in a view script?**

There is a a `layout` view helper which also gives you *direct access to the layout view model*. So you can set variables there too:

```
<?php $this->layout()->foo = 'bar';?>
```

Then `$foo` echos `bar` in your layout.